# Pagemap on memory mapped devices not working

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, mmap

I am trying to find the physical addresses of heap variables, stack variables and memory mapped peripheral addresses using the /proc/{pid}/pagemap file using the steps detailed in the file: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt. The procedure detailed works well for stack and heap variables. However, for memory mapped peripherals no page is found in the /proc/{pid}/pagemap file. The output of 'cat /proc/{pid}/maps' is:

```
00008000-0000a000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 289852     /home/linaro/ocm_test/write-memory
00011000-00012000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 289852     /home/linaro/ocm_test/write-memory
00012000-00013000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 289852     /home/linaro/ocm_test/write-memory
00013000-00034000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b2efe000-b6dfe000 rw-s 00001000 b3:02 284849     /dev/uio0
b6dfe000-b6ed2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 282416     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.15.so
b6ed2000-b6eda000 ---p 000d4000 b3:02 282416     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.15.so
b6eda000-b6edc000 r--p 000d4000 b3:02 282416     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.15.so
b6edc000-b6edd000 rw-p 000d6000 b3:02 282416     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.15.so
b6edd000-b6ee0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6ee0000-b6ee2000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 27519      /usr/lib/libinterface.so
b6ee2000-b6ee9000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 27519      /usr/lib/libinterface.so
b6ee9000-b6eea000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 27519      /usr/lib/libinterface.so
b6eea000-b6eeb000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 27519      /usr/lib/libinterface.so
b6efb000-b6f12000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 282407     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.15.so
b6f13000-b6f14000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f14000-b6f15000 rw-s 00000000 b3:02 284849     /dev/uio0
b6f15000-b6f19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f19000-b6f1a000 r--p 00016000 b3:02 282407     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.15.so
b6f1a000-b6f1b000 rw-p 00017000 b3:02 282407     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.15.so
bee36000-bee57000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
bef1f000-bef20000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

When I try to find the physical addresses of 0x00013000 or 0xbee36000 it works fine. However the page map file returns no page found when I try to find the physical address corresponding to 0xb2efe000 which belongs to /dev/uio0. I am trying to do this for verification purposes. I know a physical address exists because I have used mmap on 0x1b90000 ignored to find 0xb2efe000. Could someone please explain why the /proc/{pid}/pagemap file doesn't contain the physical address?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: The pagemap interface exposes information stored in the struct page associated with the address. I/O addresses are raw pfn mappings without an associated struct page and therefore are exposed as zeroes.

**Longer answer**
Remapping physical addresses (including I/O addresses) to userspace is done by calling `remap_pfn_range`. These remapped addresses do not have a `struct page` associated with them (they're raw pfn mappings). To remember that these addresses are special, this function sets `VM_PFNMAP` on the vma.

The pagemap interface exposes a bunch of fields that have to do with what's in the `struct page` associated with the address. But there is no such struct for these addresses. So pagemap just skips them:

When pagemap is used, the kernel does a page walk using `walk_page_range`. vmas tagged with `VM_PFNMAP` are treated differently:

```
/*
 * vma(VM_PFNMAP) doesn't have any valid struct pages behind VM_PFNMAP
 * range, so we don't walk over it as we do for normal vmas. However,
 * Some callers are interested in handling hole range and they don't
 * want to just ignore any single address range. Such users certainly
 * define their ->pte_hole() callbacks, so let's delegate them to handle
 * vma(VM_PFNMAP).
 */
```

pagemap's pte_hole just puts a bunch of zero entries (modulo some additional flag for `VM_SOFTDIRTY`). That's why you don't see it...

I don't know of any kernel interface that allows you to retrieve the physical address for such mappings. But it would be easy to do with a kernel module or using `crash`.